# symfony 2 how to make numbers appear in western arabic

Tags: php, symfony, locale

i am making an arabic website with symfony2 !
when i set the locale as "ar" for arabic, even numbers are converted in arabic !

Western Arabic  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
became:
Eastern Arabic  ٠   ١   ٢   ٣   ٤   ٥   ٦   ٧   ٨   ٩

is there a solution to make the numbers appears in the wester form ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

/**
* Converts numbers in string from western to eastern Arabic numerals.
*
* @param string $str Arbitrary text
* @return string Text with western Arabic numerals converted into eastern Arabic numerals.
*/
function arabic_w2e($str) {
$arabic_eastern = array('٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩');
$arabic_western = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
return str_replace($arabic_western, $arabic_eastern, $str);
}

/**
* Converts numbers from eastern to western Arabic numerals.
*
* @param string $str Arbitrary text
* @return string Text with eastern Arabic numerals converted into western Arabic numerals.
*/
function arabic_e2w($str) {
$arabic_eastern = array('٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩');
$arabic_western = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
return str_replace($arabic_eastern, $arabic_western, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but if someone is facing this problem
You must change the locale from ar to another arab country which doesn't use eastern numbers
for eg Tunisia

```
locale: ar_TN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this...

$standard = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$east_arabic = array(Insert numerals - my browser crashes when copy + pasting)

$string = str_replace($standard , $east_arabic , $string);